# In Carrom, What happens if the Opponent coin and striker are pocketed at the same time?

Tags: carrom

Can anyone tell me what happens if the
Opponent coin and striker are pocketed at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

You have to put your coin on board as penalty and pass the striker to the opponent

Comment: Welcome to [boardgames.se]! Please [edit] your answer to include some kind of official reference for this; right now, it has been flagged as low quality.